# Adding Commas in a function

Tags: python-2.7

On the function below, I want to add commas into the range(1,11), how do I do that?

I try doing print list(x) but it's not working...

```
def FuncA():
    Heading()
    TopMargin(10)
    LeftMargin(24)
    for x in range(1,11):
        print x,
    Pause()
    Heading()
    MENU()
```

Comment: In case you would continue using python, this may be useful: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ",".join(map(str, range(1, 11)))
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to format strings? `print "%d, " % x` should "add commas". So would `print repr(list(range(1,11)))`, with a few more characters output...